# "Person is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

My supposedly simple code isn't working. It says that *person isn't a constructor* even though I'm pretty sure it is. Please help me. I just can't get my head around it for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var people = 0;     
            function person(name, age, colour){
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
                this.colour = colour;
            }

            function triggerNew(){
                var s = document;
                s.getElementById("hiddenPers").style = "opacity: 100;"
            }

            function submitPerson(){
                var n = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var a = document.getElementById("age").value;
                var c = document.getElementById("colour").value;
                people++;
                var person = new person(n, a, c);
                alert(person1);
                document.getElementById("hiddenPers").style = "opacity: 0;"
            }

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="newPerson" onclick="triggerNew()">New Person!</button>
    <div id="hiddenPers" style="opacity: 0;">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name:"><br>
        <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Age: "><br>
        <input type="text" id="colour" placeholder="Favourite Colour:">
        <button id="submitPerson" onclick="submitPerson()">Submit Person! `</button>`
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just don't use the `new`. It's a function not a class

Comment: `alert(person1);` is this person1 a typo ?

Comment: `var person = new person(n, a, c)` name it differently. Probably `Person` for a constructor function.

Comment: Stop the debugger at the `var person = new person(n, a, c);` line. Examine the value of `person`.

Comment: also for the sake of readability name the parameters with underscore. `function Person( _name, _age, _color) { ... }`

Comment: Just don't give two different things the same name, as it only confuses everyone.

Comment: @Stavm No, that's not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

`var person = new person(n, a, c);`

to

```
var person1 = new person(n, a, c);
```

**Your code**

```js
          var people = 0;     
            function person(name, age, colour){
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
                this.colour = colour;
            }

            function triggerNew(){
                var s = document;
                s.getElementById("hiddenPers").style = "opacity: 100;"
            }

            function submitPerson(){
                var n = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var a = document.getElementById("age").value;
                var c = document.getElementById("colour").value;
                people++;
                var person1 = new person(n, a, c);
                alert(person1.name);
                document.getElementById("hiddenPers").style = "opacity: 0;"
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
  

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="newPerson" onclick="triggerNew()">New Person!</button>
    <div id="hiddenPers" style="opacity: 0;">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name:"><br>
        <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Age: "><br>
        <input type="text" id="colour" placeholder="Favourite Colour:">
        <button id="submitPerson" onclick="submitPerson()">Submit Person! `</button>`
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: below I mistakenly took `function person` and `var person` being in a single scope. Thus, while there is some truth in here, it certainly does not answer the actual question.

What you see is the hoisting order of functions and variables: function declarations come first, then variable declarations. Your `var person` overwrites `function person`.

If that sounds strange, two things to remember (or to learn):

1) hoisting means that identifiers (variables and functions) in a scope can be used before their apparent declaration. For example:

```
var a=hello();
console.log(a);
function hello(){return 5;}
```

It also applies to variables, like

```
var a=5;
function test(){
  a=2;
  var a;
  console.log("test:",a);
}
test();
console.log(a);
```

`a=2` will be internal to `test` despite of the apperent chance of referring the outer variable. (And of course, if the `var a;` line is removed/commented, the existing variable in the outer scope will be modified).

2) identifiers share a single pool, there is no separate name space for functions. That is how they can clash in your code.

```
function test(){...}
var test=function(){...};
// and both of them are invoked as test() at the end.
```

Comment: No, `var` does not overwrite `function`, and this doesn't really have to do with hoisting. It's just that the local variable *shadows* the global declaration.

Comment: @Bergi oops, you are right. Somehow I saw them being in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the constructor could also be created using a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```
var person = function (name, age, colour){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.colour = colour;
}
```

Thus this line:

```
var person = new person(n, a, c);
```

overwrites the person function with a new variable assigned to the return value from that function.

So changing the variable names should improve the situation. For example:

```js
function Person(name, age, colour){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.colour = colour;
}
var a = 15, n = "cat", c = "white";
var personInstance = new Person(n, a, c);
console.log(personInstance);
```

Additionally, as was pointed out in comments, where is `person1` coming from? Perhaps that is a typo...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, person1 was a typo, got it sorted in the end anyway.

Comment: @TonyBridle does the explanation make sense? Does it give more context about functions and declaring variables?

Comment: Okay - I am trying to gauge the value in providing detailed explanations (given [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing semicolon on line 20 and 29. Also, this line:

```
<button id="submitPerson" onclick="submitPerson()">Submit Person! `</button>`
```

Has some extra ` around the close tag.

Apart from that, the problem is here:

```
  alert(person1);
```

And it should be:

```
  alert(person1.name + person1.age + person1.colour);
```

As long as you change this:

```
  var person = new person(n, a, c);
```

To this:

```
  var person1 = new person(n, a, c);
```

```js
var people = 0;     
function person(name, age, colour){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.colour = colour;
}
function triggerNew(){
  var s = document;
  s.getElementById("hiddenPers").style = "opacity: 100;";
}
function submitPerson(){
  var n = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("colour").value;
  people++;
  var person1 = new person(n, a, c);
  alert(person1.name + person1.age + person1.colour);
  document.getElementById("hiddenPers").style = "opacity: 0;";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="newPerson" onclick="triggerNew()">New Person!</button>
    <div id="hiddenPers" style="opacity: 0;">
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name:"><br>
      <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Age: "><br>
      <input type="text" id="colour" placeholder="Favourite Colour:">
      <button id="submitPerson" onclick="submitPerson()">Submit Person!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[CodePen example:](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/oWRXEM)

Comment: Thanks. I got the problem sorted in the end, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to fix the missing semicolons;